# Cannot import azure blob storage in javascript in blazor

Tags: javascript, node.js, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using blazor client server side. We are using javascript in it for screen capture. Now i need to send mp4 file to our azure server storage. I've figured out that I need @azure/storage-blob package from node.js. I've followed this tutorial to configure node.js in browser in blazor: https://brianlagunas.com/using-npm-packages-in-blazor/ but package is not getting imported. What I am doing wrong? Here is my code in indes.js:

```
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';

export function KekTest(){
    console.log("test");
    console.log(BlobServiceClient);
}
```

**Error:** BlobServiceClient is not defined

Comment: Why don't you use the Microsoft c# package Azure.Storage.Blobs?

Comment: I recorded screen with javascript so i guess mp4 file is in browser memory and I have server side blazor so It's unnecessary to transfer file to blazor and then to azure. If I am wrong, correct me. I am just a poor junior dev :P

Comment: Well, I don't really know how NpmJS really cohabits with Blazor (never used it) and how secure it is. If it is running on client side, it definitely isn't secure (azure storage credentials). If somehow NpmJS is running on the server side, then you have to send the file to the server anyway. I try to use as much as possible c# functionalities when they exists and provide the right behaviour (without to much drawbacks).

Comment: Good point about security! Totally forget about it! So I will need to figure something else